# Boolean slicing swaps dimensions of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, numpy-slicing

for some nd-array

```
a = np.zeros((2,5,4))
```

I want to slice the last dimension based on some boolean statement.

```
a[1,:, (True,True,True,True)].shape
```

however, returns (4,5) while I would expect a shape of (5,4) like from

```
a[1,:, :].shape
```

So, what's going on here?

(This behaviour only occurs when I drop the first dimension by selecting one singular slice from it.)

Comment: It's that slice in the middle of 'advanced' indices that's producing unexpected results.  It's an obscure, but documented, corner of numpy indexing.